# How to delete Inline styles with jQuery scroll event?

Tags: jquery, css

When I scroll to 1400 and then from 1400 to top of page my chat1,2,3,4 recive "empty" inline style but only for 1s. than fadeIn goes again every time I scroll with 1 sec delay.

basically  i want to show 4 img one after another when scrolled to 1400 and than when scroll back to top i want them to disapear :)

```
(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll1 = $(window).scrollTop();

  var phoneScreen = $('.phone-screen');

  var chat1 = phoneScreen.find('#chat1');
  var chat2 = phoneScreen.find('#chat2');
  var chat3 = phoneScreen.find('#chat3');
  var chat4 = phoneScreen.find('#chat4');



  //==================== THIS PART =======================//
  if(scroll1 >= 1400){
    chat1.delay(1000).fadeIn(200, function(){
      chat2.delay(200).fadeIn(200, function(){
        chat3.delay(200).fadeIn(200, function(){
          chat4.delay(200).fadeIn(200);
        });
      });
    });

  }else{
    chat1.removeAttr('style');  // tried removeattr and .css both work the same with my example
    chat2.css('display', '');
    chat3.css('display', '');
    chat4.css('display', '');
  }
});
```

This is my CSS:

```
#chat1{
  position: relative;
  top: -1356px;
  z-index: 16;
  display: none;
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="phone-container">
    <img src="images/Tuto/phone-frame.png" alt="Phone frame">
    <div class="phone-screen">

    <img src="images/Tuto/phone-background.png" alt="Phone background" id="phone-bg">
    <img src="images/Tuto/phone-footer-explore.png" alt="phone footer explore" id="phone-fot-exp">
      <div class="profile-screen">
        <img src="images/Tuto/Joanna.png" alt="Girl Profile" id="Girl-one-prof">
        <img src="images/Tuto/szymon.png" alt="Girl Profile" id="boy-one-prof">
      </div>
    <img src="images/Tuto/match.png" alt="match" class="match">
    <img src="images/Tuto/chat.png" alt="chat" id="chat">
    <img src="images/Tuto/chat1.png" alt="chat1" id="chat1">
    <img src="images/Tuto/chat2.png" alt="chat2" id="chat2">
    <img src="images/Tuto/chat3.png" alt="chat3" id="chat3">
    <img src="images/Tuto/chat4.png" alt="chat4" id="chat4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your goal/problem here, what do you expect happen when you scroll past 1400px? and what when you scroll <1400px?

Comment: when (scroll1 >= 1400) i wanna show some img , then when i scroll to top  scroll < 1400px i want them to disapear.

Comment: `chat1.hide()` ???

Comment: can you post relevant html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whould you consider using fixed-positioned elements for the job?

Also, everytime you scroll up, you are triggering an animation on each `img`, animation that take their sweet time to kick in and complete, so `.hide()` was in out of it's depth trying to hide an object being affected by an ongoing animation; enters `.stop(true)` to save the day and, [I quote](https://api.jquery.com/stop/), *Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements*.

You could even refactor this code to make it trigger the animations ONLY ONCE when it passes the 1400px mark, and ONLY again when it passes it upwards.

```js
$('.phone-screen').children('img').each(function(i){
  $(this).css('top', i * $(this).prev().height());
});
$(window).scroll(function() {

var scroll1 = $(window).scrollTop();

var phoneScreen = $('.phone-screen');

var chat1 = phoneScreen.find('#chat1');
var chat2 = phoneScreen.find('#chat2');
var chat3 = phoneScreen.find('#chat3');
var chat4 = phoneScreen.find('#chat4');

//==================== THIS PART =======================//
if(scroll1 >= 1400){
    chat1.delay(1000).fadeIn(200, function(){
        chat2.delay(200).fadeIn(200, function(){
            chat3.delay(200).fadeIn(200, function(){
                chat4.delay(200).fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    });

}else{
  $('[id^="chat"]').stop(true).hide();
}
});
```

```css
[id^="chat"]{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 16;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="phone-screen">
  <img id="chat1" alt="chat1">
  <img id="chat2" alt="chat2">
  <img id="chat3" alt="chat3">
  <img id="chat4" alt="chat4">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, U showed me a new approach to my scroll animation. I gues i need to make it all over again using what u showed me :) cause there are more elements as You can see in my html. :) thanks a lot